# Mosquitto MQTT - Not able to connect from external client

Tags: linux-networking, ubuntu-14.04

Ok, this has been throwing me for a loop for the past few days.

## Information

I have Mosquitto MQTT 1.4.10 with WebSockets enabled setup and running on Ubuntu Server 14.4. Any client on my LAN can connect to the broker using port 1883 (mqtt) and 9001 (websockets) and everything works fine. Now I also have a public IP address and setup port forwarding on my DD-WRT router to route 1883 and 9001 to the server's address. I have disabled my firewall (*sudo ufw disable*) and confirmed it is disabled.

## Issue

1. I connect my phone with OwnTracks running to my local WiFi. I enter the MQTT server IP with port 1883 and it works. I enter the public IP with port 1883 and it works. Then I disconnect from my local WiFi so I am just using my cell network. I try connecting again using my public IP and port 1883 and it doesn't work.

Checking the log I see:

```
New connection from <<external_ip>> on port 1883
Socket error on client <unknown>, disconnecting
```

Check my config file and all looks good there to:

```
pid_file /var/run/mosquitto.pid

persistence true
persistence_location /var/lib/mosquitto/

log_dest file /var/log/mosquitto/mosquitto.log
log_type all

include_dir /etc/mosquitto/conf.d

listener 1883
protocol mqtt

listener 9001 127.0.0.1
protocol websockets
```

Checked to make sure Ubuntu is listen on the ports specified:

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:1883            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:2216            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:9001            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:10000           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 :::1883                 :::*                    LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 :::2216                 :::*                    LISTEN
```

One last thing that trips me up is that I can connect on 9001 using web sockets from any client connected to either my LAN or WAN. I would think that being bound to to the local loop-back address would allow it to accept only connections from its self.

Any ideas on how to get 1883 to accept client from outside my LAN?